# "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable", but it works just fine in my other code

Tags: python, web-scraping, int, typeerror, iterable

I am trying to scrape data from https://www.teamrankings.com/ and am having some difficulty. I have set up a few similar programs in the past when creating csvs from webscraping, but this one is giving me some trouble. I keep getting a `TypeError` in one specific for loop, but a different program I have with essentially the same code works just fine. I'm sure there is a simple fix for this but I have been unable to find one.

I have tried the suggested fixes given by Pycharm, but none of them fix anything. And by changing the variable to type `object`, it then says objects of type `None` cannot be iterated either.

```
for tr in rows:
    cells = tr.find("td")
    temp = []
    for td in cells:
        x = 0
        if(x == 2):
            temp.append(td.get_text())
        x+=1
    data.append(temp)
```

I only posted the code that was giving the error message, but can post more if that would be helpful. All of the error messages were some sort of `TypeError`, typically `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. I tried doing with `range(cells)` and `range(len(cells))` but both of those fixes failed.

Meanwhile, from the working program (scraping from a different website), the following code worked:

```
for tr in rows:
    cells = div.find("right")
    temp = []
    for right in cells:
        temp.append(data.get_text())
    data.append(temp)
```

To me this looks the same, which is why I am confused. The goal, as stated, is to make a csv, but so far no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

means that the thing you're trying to iterate over (e.g. the `cells` in your `for td in cells`) isn't a `List` of things as you may have thought, it's a single thing (an `int`).

Seeing how `tr` was defined (I assume it was created by some web-scraping Python module, but which one?) would make it easier to suggest a fix, but I think the crux of the issue is that you're expecting `tr.find("td")` to return a list of some kind of "cell" object, and instead it's giving you a single `int`.

If you can find the documentation that explains why this `find()` method returns an `int`, that might help you find a different method that will return the `List` you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`find` only ever returns a single item not a list. It returns the first match. Both codes shown I would expect to see fail. `findall` is the correct method to return a list; however, I see no `table` elements (nor `td`) at the specified URI meaning that you cells should be `None`. Was login required?

Your bottom code also should fail due to:

```
temp = []
for right in cells:
    temp.append(data.get_text())
data.append(temp)
```

You are using the variable `data` twice and not using `temp`, other than to attempt to append it as an empty list to what presumably what was a list called `data` but in the loop you have tried to call `get_text()` on it.